# Java: Access Fields without knowing their names. ("Save reference")

Tags: java, orm, field

I need to get a `Field` (or a list of Fields) without knowing it's name.

I.e: for a custom entitymanager i'd like to be able to do Method Calls like this:

`cem.getEntities(MyEntity.class, ParamMap)` where the ParamMap should be of the Type `Map<Field, Object>`.

What i *can* do at the moment is something like this:

```
Map<Field, Object> params = new HashMap<Field, Object>();
params.put(MyEntity.class.getDeclaredField("someFieldName"), 20);
List<MyEntity> entitysWithSomeFieldNameEquals20 = cem.getEntities(MyEntity.class, params);
```

Im trying to avoid the usage of querys, because it should work "generic" in the first place, but also be independent from Strings. (They are error-prone). The Entity Manager therefore uses reflection to determine the table and column names, he needs to use.

However, I STILL need to use

```
MyEntity.class.getDeclaredField("someFieldName")
```

which will simple move the error-prone string "out" of the entity manager...

What i'm trying to achieve would be something like this:

```
MyEntity.class.getDeclaredField(MyEntity.class.fields.someFieldName.toString())
```

So, no matter what the actual field is named, it can be referenced in a save way and refactoring will refactor all the field-access calls, too.

I'm not sure if this is possible. I could go with a (encapsuled) enum for ALL entities, but I hope, that theres a more generic way to achieve this.

---

Edit:

One good solution seems to be the usage of constants:

```
public class MyEntity{
    private static string SOME_FIELD = "some_field_name_in_database";

    @Column(name = SOME_FIELD);
    private String someField;

}

...
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put(MyEntity.SOME_FIELD, matchValue);
List<MyEntity> result = eem.getEntities(MyEntity.class, params);
```

This at least reduces the usage of the string to exactly one location, where it can be maintained and changed without affecting any other file. But im still searching for a solution without constants, so the contants *don't need to be synchronized with the available fields* :-)

Comment: You want to swim but without getting wet? What is wrong about a Property-Collection with String-Keys? As soon as you make them an enum or something alike, they won't be "generic" anymore. So I think your requirements contradict each other.

Comment: But you do know the field's name (here it's "someFieldName")? Otherwise, how do you want to fill the ParamMap with values not knowing the fields' names? I guess the issue here is that you do not want to use Strings?

Comment: Yes, sure i know the fieldnames. But i don't want to put them (hardcoded) into Strings. So the question is, if i can reference them in a way, like using an enum, without creating an enum for every entity (that needs to be maintained). Using an embedded Enum per entity is not working, because JPA doesn't allow to grab columnnames from an enum (column.name needs to be a constant expression)... Don't get me wrong: Changing an entity will always result in work to do. But you can't find every single usage of a certain string, like you can reference the usage of enums / Constants.

Comment: By the way, getDeclaredField on Class throws NuSuchFieldException. So, even if you use Strings, you will fail fast in case you make a typo. You will get this at run-time, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: @proskor That is EXACTLY why i try to avoid stringusage. (First i removed strings from the EM, by passing fields. But now i need to determine fields without strings) :)

Comment: What about instantiating the MyEntity class, populating its fields with the required values (which will be checked at compile time), and passing the instance to getEntities instead of the map? Or, in case you insist on using a map, inspecting the instance and generating the map based on that? Hibernate use something similar in the Criteria API: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples.

Comment: @proskor: Thought about that, too. Create a `PatternInstance` so to say. Only problem: how can I *securly* determine then if `patternInstange.getAttribute1()`, which returns an empty string does mean: *This attribute HAS to be an empty string* OR *This attribute doesn't matter*. (and same szenario for NULL Values ofc. - Du i want Entrys where XY is null, or does patternInstance.XY = null mean it doesn't matter?) Therefore having an explicit defined Map of Attributes seems better to handle.

Comment: I think the constants-solution from your edit is the closest you can get. I mean that's one place to touch, if the fieldname changes. I could think of getting a columnname for key in a hashmap from a db table's metadata...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is just an idea, which is not easy to implement, but it could work.

Suppose MyEntity looks like this:

```
public class MyEntity {
  private String foo;
  private String bar;

  public String getFoo() { return this.foo; }
  public void setFoo(String foo) { this.foo = foo; }

  public String getBar() { return this.bar; }
  public void setBar(String bar) { this.bar = bar; }
```

}

and there is an interface:

```
public interface Pattern {
  public Class<?> getEntityClass();
  public Map<Field, Object> getFields();
}
```

and there is a method, which takes a class and generates a pattern object, which is an instance of the given class:

```
public class PatternFactory {
  public <T> T createPattern(Class<T> klass) {
    // magic happens here
  }
}
```

The requirement for the emitted instance would be that it should implement the `Pattern` interface, such that the method getFields returns only the fields which were explicitly set. GetEntityClass should return the entity class. Then the custom entity manager could be implemented like this:

```
public class EntityManager {
  public <T> Collection<T> getEntities(T pattern) {
    if (!(pattern instanceof Pattern))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    Class<?> klass = ((Pattern) pattern).getEntityClass();
    Map<Field, Object> fields = ((Pattern) pattern).getFields();
    // fetch objects here
  }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
PatternFactory pf = // obtain somehow
EntityManager em = // obtain somehow
MyEntity pattern = pf.createPattern(MyEntity.class);
pattern.setFoo("XYZ");
pattern.setBar(null);
Collection<MyEntity> result = em.getEntities(pattern);
```

In this case pattern.getFields would return a map with two entries.

The difficulty here lies, of course, in the implementation of the createPattern method, where you will have to emit bytecode at run-time. However, this is possible and can be done.